# Get error while pull data between two dates in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get data between start_date and end_date but the query return an Unknown column error here is my code.

```
    if($start_date != '' && $end_date != '' && $exp_type != '')
    {
        $this->db->where("tbl_expenses.created_date BETWEEN " . $start_date . " AND ". $end_date); [Error occur bcz of this line]
        $this->db->where("tbl_expenses.expense_type",$exp_type);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        $data['searched_data'] = $result->result();
        $this->load->view('admin/filter_result_view',$data);

    }
```

Error is: [image]

Thanks to all for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change error line as below. `$start_date` and `$end_date` should be enclosed between quotes. And in this case `$this->db->get()` should have  within the `get()` method.

Updated code as below:

```
if($start_date != '' && $end_date != '' && $exp_type != '')
{
    $this->db->where("(tbl_expenses.created_date BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND '". $end_date . "')");
    $this->db->where("tbl_expenses.expense_type",$exp_type);
    $result = $this->db->get('tbl_expenses');
    $data['searched_data'] = $result->result();
    $this->load->view('admin/filter_result_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: Sachin i change this but now it show me this error:                            
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `tbl_expenses`.`created_date` = '2017-01-04' AND `tbl_expenses`.`expense_t' at line 2

Comment: Try like this and let me know. `$this->db->where("(tbl_expenses.created_date BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND '". $end_date . "')");`

Comment: what query it has generated?

Comment: This one : [ SELECT * WHERE `tbl_expenses`.`created_date` = '2017-01-04' AND `tbl_expenses`.`expense_type` = '1' ]

Comment: change `$result = $this->db->get();` to `$result = $this->db->get('<table_name>');` where <table_name> is name of the table you are fetching the data

Comment: return this : [ Table 'rent_a_car.' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM `tbl_expenses`, `` WHERE (`tbl_expenses`.`created_date` BETWEEN '2017-01-04' AND '2017-10-04') AND `tbl_expenses`.`expense_type` = '1' ] but rent_a_car is DB name.

Comment: can you please send it to me i didn't know which one you are talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142069/discussion-between-sachin-patil-and-hazrat-bilal).

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this line instead of your error line

$this->db->where("tbl_expenses.created_date BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date);

Comment: please check your input format ie., start_date and database field date format

Comment: please add $this->db->from("tbl_expenses");

Comment: Vimal Kumar E before if statement i changed to the required format and both format are same.

Comment: please change the datetime to date in database

Comment: you pass the value as date format but in your table stored in the value as date and time

Comment: created_date type is also date not datetime

Comment: $this->db->from('tbl_expenses');
  
 $this->db->where('tbl_expenses.createdOn >=', $start_date);

$this->db->where('tbl_expenses.createdOn <=', $end_date);